# SQL search for "firstName + ' ' + lastName" works even if someone enters firstName two times

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

When making a query to database I have to provide a querstring and when I add a part with `"AND userName ILIKE '" + firstName + " " + lastName + "'"` it works well, only shows results when someone puts correct first name AND last name, but now I realized it also works when you put first name or last name two times in the search. So if you put first name: John, last name: John, it will still find a John Smith in the database and I really don't want it to happen.

Comment: Why you don't write a function to compare the first name and last name before executing the query?

Comment: Are you saying you would like to use OR in LIKE? firstName LIKE 'John' OR lastName LIKE 'Smith_'

Comment: Can you show the actual query string? Verbatim? (I can't replicate this)

Comment: the part of query string that I am talking about looks like this:     `queryString += " AND customerName ILIKE '" + pdict.firstName + " " + pdict.lastName + "'";`
I don't know how it starts, because it's and old code and I can't see all of it. 
What I want is to show results for "John Smith" only if someone enters valid first name and last name. So "John" + "S" shouldn't work (and it doesn't), but for some reason "John" + "John" works...

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, there's no "John John" in the database? This works for other first names, too? I can't imagine why; is there no way to properly debug this and look at the full query? And why is this tagged with javascript?

Comment: There is no John John in this database,but if there was one I want the function to find him too, but only if the user puts in first name "John" and last name "John" in the app (actually it worked for Piotr Piotr, and found Piotr Dawidziuk, which is me). There is no way to look at full query because it's commercecloud and it doesn't show you the code that's under it's methods. And it's tagged as JavaScript, because the function is actually written in JavaScript.

Comment: I actually made it work when I did something like `var fullName = pdict.firstName + " " + pdict.lastName; queryString += " AND customerName = '" + fullName + "'";` but now it's case sensitive and I need it to be case insensitive.

Comment: Ok, so using `=` instead of `ILIKE` will fix it? In that case turn both values uppercase first.

Comment: I can't turn a value inside the query string to uppercase, it gives me an error, but I can filter the result after. Thanks!! :)